# Why doesn't my scanner show up in my for-loop?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here is my code. All help will be greatly appreciated. PS I'm not making a scam or anything like that, the top part is supposed to be a joke.

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

```
public class ShoppingSpree//Nick
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     int maxitems = 3;
     double damountofmoneywon = 100.00;
     double moneyleft = damountofmoneywon;
     for(moneyleft = 100.00; moneyleft == 0.00;)
     {
     System.out.println("You have won $100 for being the 1,000,000 visitor to this       site.");
     System.out.println("You may buy up to 3 items costing no more than $100.");
     System.out.println("Enter the cost of your item: ");
     Scanner itemonecost = new Scanner(System.in);
     double ditemonecost = itemonecost.nextDouble();
     if(ditemonecost <= moneyleft)
       {
       System.out.println("You have enough money for this item.");
       moneyleft = moneyleft - ditemonecost;
       }
     else if(moneyleft == 0)
       {
         System.out.println("You have no more money");
         break;
       }
      else
       {
         System.out.println("You don't have enough money, try again");
      }                 
     }
   }
```

}

Comment: Check your for loop, it's not incrementing anything.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't show up? Also, only construct the `Scanner` once (outside the for-loop).

Comment: @Bloomfield What about `moneyleft = moneyleft - ditemonecost;`?

Comment: Well it depends on how long you want the loop to last, though to me it seems like you want a while loop as long as there is another integer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to invert the moneyleft termination condition in the for loop to be

```
for(moneyleft = 100.00; moneyleft > 0.00;)
```

At the moment it's immediately evaluating to **false** so the loop terminates without beginning.

EDIT:

Better yet, you can remove the line

```
double moneyleft = damountofmoneywon;
```

and fix your *for* conditional to be:

```
for(double moneyleft = damountofmoneywon; moneyleft > 0.00;)
```

Because as it is currently the assignment to damountofmoneywon is being lost in the assignment to 100.0

Comment: You still need an increment/decrement condition in the declaration of the for loop, or else infinite loops while happen.

Comment: This is covered by
    moneyleft = moneyleft - ditemonecost

Comment: Huh I didn't realize if you declared a variable before the header, you could use it in the body of the for loop to control when it terminates.